# can we full fill getWritableDatabase() and getReadableDatabase() request same time in android sqlite DB

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to request some data from SQLite DB in the Android app from two threads.So is it possible to call getReadableDatabase() and getWritableDatabase() at same time on same instance of db in android.

Comment: yes on button click you can insert and read data from database.

Comment: if you go ddep in to sqlite opne helper all you see is writeable . thats wird but it is what it is . so you can live with writeable in both cases

Comment: There's an interesting comment in API which could throw water on this: for the 'getReadableDatabase' return value "a database object valid until getWritableDatabase() or close() is called."

Comment: Simultaneously am calling two threads, from one thread, am calling getReadableDatabase () and from another thread am calling getWritableDatabase() . So is it possible to both the access same time?

Comment: Given that the database instance is cached by helper, if the thread calling `getWritableDatabase` executes _first_ (and thus is the one opening the database) then the thread calling `getReadableDatabase` will always get the writeable instance!  The opposite scenario seems problematic to me given the API comment mentioned above.  The source may be a helpful reference in this case: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible but you need to be careful because if you call `close` to close the connection with the db the other thread will crash if it's trying to read/write.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes but also No in some situations.

Basically `getReadableDatabase` will get a **"writable"** database unless the database can only be read. Whilst `getWritableDatabase` would fail if the database were not writable.

As per :-

> **getReadableDatabase** *added in API level 1 SQLiteDatabase*
>
> **getReadableDatabase()**
>
> Create and/or open a database.
>
> This will be the
>   same object returned by **`getWritableDatabase()`** unless some problem,
>   such as a full disk, requires the database to be opened read-only. In
>   that case, a read-only database object will be returned.
>
> If the
>   problem is fixed, a future call to **`getWritableDatabase()`** may succeed,
>   in which case the read-only database object will be closed and the
>   read/write object will be returned in the future.

[getReadableDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase())

So if the database is writable then definitely **Yes** but if the database is only readable then there is a chance that `getWritableDatabase` would fail and hence the No for this likely rare situation.

Typically, unless specifically wanting to handle the situation where the database cannot be opened for write, using `getWritableDatabase` is probably really what is wanted. i.e. Really `getReadableDatabase` allows you some access should the database not be writable but can be read. It will generally not protect against writing/updating the database.